# Mobile Windscreen Repair Quotes/Jobs Database Design

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, object-role-modeling

After reading a number of stackoverflow articles, I struggled to find any help with my database design.

I'm working on a student project for University. I need to build a quote management and job management system for the client. The client owns a Mobile Windscreen Repair and Replacement service, and needs to store quotes and jobs.

I've thought about tables such as: **Customer, Vehicle, Repair, Inventory, Address, Employees** but do not know the best way to do the quotes and job tables and a general ER diagram.

Any suggested would be great!

Comment: If you need to use the Entity-Relationship model, Peter Chen's paper `The Entity-Relationship Model: Toward a Unified View of Data` is the most useful reference, and it's not long. If you can use Object-Role Modeling, see http://orm.net. Try to do a logical model first and let that determine the tables.

Comment: That's quite a big model you've been asked for! I would ask your teacher whether they have created a complete answer to the question themselves. I would suggest that you don't start by choosing tables - just make a list of all the things, including all the small things (names, etc). Write down the main relationships, and then you'll have a chance at finding the right tables. You might find value in the example models (in CQL) at http://dataconstellation.com

Comment: @cliffordheath indeed! Unfortunately it's a final year project so the client was someone I had to find and gather Requirements from. Hence the complexity of the model! Implementation isn't the focus right now, focus is on the system analysis and design

Comment: @reaanb thank you! Will have to check this out!

Comment: I would quote two weeks to do this to a professional standard (including multiple review cycles), and I count myself a world-class modeller. Consider finding a way to simplify your task.